# Split upper and lowercase in the same word into two lines

Tags: regex, icu

I have a string like this

```
Text Text TextText Text Text T5df Tdfcv TextNeu
```

In other words:

If there is a change from Lowercase to Uppercase within a word, this is where a new line should be inserted as `\n`.

So the example would convert to

```
Text Text Text\nText Text Text T5df Tdfcv Text\nNeu
```

I am using ICU regex.

I tried `"[\p{Upper}]"`, which matches all uppercase literals, but not with a preceding lowercase in the same word.

Also I need to know what to replace it with as regex.

How do I accomplish that?

Comment: Use `(?<=\p{Ll})(?=\p{Lu})`, replace with a `\n`.

Comment: That works. But how did you come up with that?

Comment: It is simple: `(?<=\p{Ll})` is a positive lookbehind matching a location immediately after lowercase letter and `(?=\p{Lu})` is a positive lookahead that requires an uppercase letter immediately to the right of the current location. So, it matches a location in a string between a lower- and an uppercase letter (because lookarounds do not advance the regex index when their patterns are matched).